# Programmable Chat - Xamarin Forms Chat App for Windows (UWP) and Mac in future

Tags: twilio

We are building a chat client in Xamarin Forms (.NET, PCL) for Windows 10 (UWP), Android, iOS and for Mac in future. 
We are evaluating Twilio Programmable Chat as a platform to built on. 
Is there a .NET SDK (PCL or non-PCL) that we can use to build the client?
Or can we built one of our own using a .NET socket library of our own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no .NET SDK currently available, however Xamarin SDK is planned (no exact date, we'll try to get it going ASAP). You can always use generated wrappers to access the REST API from your application or write your own. The API documentation on the site should be sufficient to get you going, but if you have any specific questions - feel free to ask on SO or from Twilio Support.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do I listen in real-time for a new message, chat request and so on? I should be able to hook up to your websockets, correct?

Comment: It's more involved and will be hard to implement for client using only REST API. You could wrap some native SDK of course, but that'll also take time and effort.